# Xcode SQLite - is there a simpler way?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ios5, sqlite

This is a general question and not the usual StackOverflow "can someone please correct my syntax mistake..."

SQL is the most wonderfully condensed language, so in one line I can save a record. e.g.

```
INSERT INTO database VALUES (4,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2', 'Stavanger')
```

But if I want to save/insert a record in Cocoa with SQLite I'll end up writing closer to 14, e.g.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", name.text, address.text, phone.text];    
const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];         
sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
self.status.text = @"Contact added";
self.name.text = @"";
self.address.text = @"";
self.phone.text = @"";
} else {
self.status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼    ￼}
    }

I understand what each line is doing but as a Cocoa/SQLite newbie all I want to double check is if there is a simpler way or if I just have to regurgitate this level of verbosity every time I want to do the tritest SQL command...

Many thanks￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Answer (score 1):

[Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (an excellent SQLite wrapper).

Comment: Apologies for taking so long in thanking you. I've been reading around this and although I am sure FMDB is the answer I haven't found much documentation. Can anyone recommend a good repository of examples I could learn from?

Comment: @EdwardHasted FMDB itself [comes with an example](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb.m) of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could create a function that accepts both the SQL query and the database name.  One great use of functions is to simplify the process of writing code.